# Where is python on mac? (osx el capitan)

Tags: python

I'm trying to download pygame on my computer and use it, but from what I've seen, I need the 32-bit python not the 64-bit one I have. however, I cannot find where the file is on my computer to delete it. I looked through all of my files with the name of 'python' but nothing has shown up about the 64-bit pre installed program. Anyone know how to find it?

Comment: From your terminal, type `which python` to find the path to your Python installation. If you want to know the version of Python that you are running, run `python --version`.

Comment: You probably don't want to remove the version of Python installed on your computer. Very likely it is being used for some system processes. Instead, add the other version.

Comment: I don't think you need 32-bit Python. Definitely **don't mess with the system version of `python`** - you can break a lot of things really bad that way.

Answer (score 0):

Type 
`which python`
on terminal.